# How to get original indexpath in filtered uitableview swift 3 using Multiselection

Tags: ios, swift3

have a uitableView that need to search on it. When I click on a cell it shows an indicator in that cell(it is multi selection table). Every thing works very well up to here. However, **when I search something and back to original table the returned index is not the original index and it indicates a wrong cell.** I see a lot of question in stackoverflow but they use storyboards or they are in Objective-c that I don't understand.

> How can I get original indexPath (multi selected) in searched table?

import UIKit

code..............

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate
{

    var marrCountryList: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var marrFilteredCountryList: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var selectedArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()


    @IBOutlet var tblCountry: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        marrCountryList = ["FRK","USA", "Bahamas", "Brazil", "Canada", "Republic of China", "Cuba", "Egypt", "Fiji", "France", "Germany", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Jamaica", "Kenya", "Madagascar", "Mexico", "Nepal", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Poland", "Singapore", "Somalia", "Switzerland", "Turkey", "UAE", "Vatican City"]
        self.tblCountry.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            return self.marrFilteredCountryList.count
        }
        else
        {
            return self.marrCountryList.count
        }
    }

    @IBAction func btnnewSubmit(_ sender: Any) {

        let objReg=self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewTableViewController") as! ViewTableViewController
        print("submite button tapped...")
        objReg.abc = selectedArray
        print(selectedArray)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objReg, animated: true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cellCountry = self.tblCountry.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        var countryName : String!
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView
        {
            countryName = marrFilteredCountryList[indexPath.row] as! String
            tblCountry.reloadData()
        }
        else
        {
            countryName = marrCountryList[indexPath.row] as! String

        }

        if selectedArray.contains(self.marrCountryList.object(at: indexPath.row) as! String)
        {
            let checkImage = UIImage(named:"check")
            let checkers = UIImageView(image: checkImage)
            cellCountry.accessoryView = checkers
        }
        else
        {
            let uncheckImage = UIImage(named:"uncheck")
            let unchecker = UIImageView(image: uncheckImage)
            cellCountry.accessoryView = unchecker
        }

        cellCountry.textLabel?.text = countryName

        return cellCountry
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        {

            if selectedArray.contains(self.marrCountryList.object(at: indexPath.row) as! String)
            {
                let uncheckImage = UIImage(named:"uncheck")
                let unchecker = UIImageView(image: uncheckImage)
                cell.accessoryView = unchecker
                selectedArray.remove(self.marrCountryList.object(at: indexPath.row) as! String)
                tblCountry.reloadData()

            }
            else
            {
                let checkImage = UIImage(named:"check")
                let checkers = UIImageView(image: checkImage)
                cell.accessoryView = checkers
                selectedArray.add(self.marrCountryList.object(at: indexPath.row) as! String)
                tblCountry.reloadData()


            }


        }

        var object :AnyObject?
        if(self.searchDisplayController?.isActive)! {
            object = marrFilteredCountryList[indexPath.row] as AnyObject
        }
        else {
            object = self.marrCountryList[indexPath.row] as AnyObject
        }

    }

    func filterTableViewForEnterText(_ searchText: String) {
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)

        let array = (self.marrCountryList as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
        self.marrFilteredCountryList = array as! [String] as! NSMutableArray

    }

    func searchDisplayController(_ controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearch searchString: String?) -> Bool
    {
        self.filterTableViewForEnterText(searchString!)
        return true
    }

    func searchDisplayController(_ controller: UISearchDisplayController,
        shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool
    {

            self.filterTableViewForEnterText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text!)
            return true
    }

}
```

Comment: There must be two array one is serached array and other is normal (will all data) and on didselect you may check with BOOL value and you will get indexPath based on array which use in tableview.

Comment: Sir Nitin Gohel Please help with Explain for Example code  @NitinGohel